# Main page xaml to manage user control events

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I need an elegant solution (I am working on silverlight 4.0) to solve this simple problem(?) using the MVVM pattern:

My mainpage xaml has my two custom user controls like this (say):

```
<uc:MyCustomUC1>
<uc:MyCustomUC2>
```

Each one has its own view model and both these user controls are independent of each other.

When an asynchronous operation in MyCustomUC1 has completed, I want an ICommand in MyCustomUC2's viewmodel to be invoked thus refreshing data in MyCustomUC2. I want this done by the parent page and all in  xaml.
Exposing dependency properties, event handlers etc in the user controls...anything is ok since I own the user control ...whatever makes sense.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It seems like both answers below would work but is not simple enough for me (sorry, I'll do some more reading on your answers). Meanwhile, I am looking into using attached behaviors as a solution. Kind of like it so far but have not completed my idea. Will get back to this soon.

Answer (score 1):

Use Mvvm Lights messenger, you can register a listener in MyCustomUC2's viewmodel to refresh.  Then in MyCustomUC1's async call back, send the message to refresh.

Comment: This seems to be too much work - 3rd party classes and lots of code. Isn't there a simpler using existing classes ?

Comment: I believe that the MVVMlight Messenger class (Observer pattern) is just right for what you need and it won't be too much work, in fact it will make your life easier.

Messenger.Default.Send<T>(payload); Messenger.Default.Subscribe<T>(SomeMethod)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PropertyObserver, which I believe you can find info on here:
[Property Observer](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/).

It'll allow you to check when something has changed in one ViewModel and then take the appropriate action in another. I've used this quite a bit recently in a project and it has worked pretty well.

Apologies if I've picked up the question incorrectly.

Comment: Once I add the property observer to the view models, can the parent control this purely in xaml ?

Comment: @DeeStackOverflow: Yes it can.